# Using xypic in Texmacs.

Tags: xy-pic

**Question:** When I try to "start up" the xypic interactive thing in texmacs, it just writes "Busy..." and never evaluates anything I put in.  What am I doing wrong?

**Motivation:** I just started to use Texmacs and I find it to be a little bit easier for my purposes.  Unfortunately, a lot of what I do uses commutative diagrams and, therefore, \xypic makes my life a whole lot easier.  I just cannot find any documentation anywhere on this.

(I'm also not sure exactly what to tag this, since there doesn't seem to be any texmacs tags...)

Comment: If you search documentation on xypic, see the excellent http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/pub/mirrors/CTAN/macros/generic/diagrams/xypic/xy/doc/xyguide.pdf If you want a precise response that take count of Texmacs, please add a minimal example.

Comment: There is a forum for Texmacs at http://forum.texmacs.cn/